# Copy table data on same server with field remapping

Tags: mysql, enums

I need to copy the data of an old table with millions of rows to a newer table, with a slightly different definition. Most importantly, there is one new field with a null-default, and a varchar field became an enum (with directly mapping values).

Old table:

- id : integer
- type : varchar

New table:

- id : integer
- type : **enum**
- number : integer, default null

All of the possible string values of `type` are within the new enumeration.

I tried the following:

```
insert into new.table select * from old.table
```

But I obviously get:

> Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: insert into t1 (x,y,z) select a,b,c from t2

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the table data and structure from phpmyadmin window, and then modify the new table and add the new column.

[image]

Comment: I cannot use a graphical interface; I'm calling this from a script.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `new.table` LIKE `old_table`;  copies the structure as far as I know and INSERT INTO `new.table` SELECT * FROM `oldtable`; copies the data , also using reserved words such as table would cause a problem

Answer (score 0):

Using the `INSERT ... SELECT` [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO new.table `id`, `type` SELECT `id`, `type` FROM old.table
```

Apparently the varchar to enum remapping isn't a problem.